# Random sampling of a string slice

Tags: rust

The objective is to take a set number of random samples from a string slice.

```rust
fn get_random_samples<'a>(kmers: &'a [&'a str], sample_size: usize) -> &'a [&'a str] {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers
        .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
        .map(|item| *item)
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
        .as_slice()
}
```

But the above code gives the following compilation error which I have no idea how to fix.

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
   --> src\lib.rs:382:5
    |
382 |        kmers
    |   _____^
    |  |_____|
    | ||
383 | ||         .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
384 | ||         .map(|item| *item)
385 | ||         .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
    | ||_______________________________- temporary value created here
386 | |          .as_slice()
    | |____________________^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return the `Vec` directly (and remove the unnecessarily restrictive lifetime on the outer slice of `kmers`). Also, you can use [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) instead of `map` with deref.

```rust
fn get_random_samples<'a>(kmers: &[&'a str], sample_size: usize) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers
        .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
        .copied()
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
}
```

[Playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd238eec158e79c701a9a23b533ca1c5)

Comment: Thanks!. That works really well. 

Just a general question. The vector from this function will later be passed to another function completely unaltered. In this case, wouldn't having a slice be preferred?

Comment: @Shane Awesome! You're right, if the other function only needs a slice, it should have a slice as the parameter. The caller can convert the `Vec` to a slice via `vec.as_slice()` or `&vec[..]` or similar. The reason `get_random_samples` can't do it is that it doesn't know how long to keep the memory alive / when to free it, whereas the caller knows it can free it if it's done using it.