# Cannot move out of `*X` which is behind a shared reference when using Box

Tags: rust

I understand the reason why this error is being raised, but not sure how I should go about fixing it. Ideally I would want to avoid using `Copy`.

```rust
fn get_random_samples<'a>(kmers: &[Box<str>], sample_size: usize) -> Vec<Box<str>> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers
        .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
        .map(|item| *item)
        .collect::<Vec<Box<str>>>()
}
```

This raises the compilation error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*item` which is behind a shared reference
   --> src\lib.rs:384:21
    |
384 |         .map(|item| *item)
    |                     ^^^^^ move occurs because `*item` has type `Box<str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I've also tried:

```rust
fn get_random_samples<'a>(kmers: &[Box<str>], sample_size: usize) -> Vec<Box<str>> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers
        .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
        .copied()
        .collect::<Vec<Box<str>>>()
}
```

as learned from a previous question ([Random sampling of a string slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934594/random-sampling-of-a-string-slice)), but this raises a different error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<str>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
    --> src\lib.rs:384:10
     |
384  |         .copied()
     |          ^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `Box<str>`
     |
note: required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::copied`
    --> C:\Users\shant\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\iter\traits\iterator.rs:2987:12
     |
2987 |         T: Copy,
     |            ^^^^ required by this bound in `std::iter::Iterator::copied`
```

Both errors seem to point to the `Copy` trait which ideally I would like to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated!.

PS: Quite new to Rust, please do suggest if there's better ways to do this.

Comment: Try `.map(|item| item.to_string().into_boxed _str()`. If you don't want to copy the strings, you'll need to change the return type to `Vec<&'a str>`, where `'a` is the lifetime used for the `kmers` slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid copying/cloning, you need to return a reference. For example:

```rust
use rand::prelude::SliceRandom;
fn get_random_samples(kmers: &[Box<str>], sample_size: usize) -> Vec<&Box<str>> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers
        .choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size)
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef6739f75041036707271fd3dfcb0434)

or:

```rust
use rand::prelude::SliceRandom;
fn get_random_samples(kmers: &[Box<str>], sample_size: usize) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    kmers.choose_multiple(&mut rng, sample_size).map(|e| e as &str).collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8819bc6abb7adc7de695567241b732da)